# debo dar clic al elemento // * [@ id = \ “menu-content \”] / a [1] / li / h3 , almacenado en el tercer frame java, no ha sido posible

Tags: java

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>NetIQ iManager</title>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/nps/portal/modules/dev/images/favicon.png">
  <script src="moz-extension://5847c9bb-864b-490f-93d1-2d752bab5c66/assets/prompt.js"></script>
  <script src="moz-extension://5847c9bb-864b-490f-93d1-2d752bab5c66/assets/prompt.js"></script>
</head>
<frameset rows="88,*,0" framespacing="0" frameborder="0" onload="top.name='eMFrame'" id="iManagerRootFrame">
  <frame src="webacc?taskId=fw.Header&amp;merge=fw.iManagerHeader" id="Branding_ID" name="Branding" title="${requestScope['FrameTitle.HeaderFrame']}" noresize="" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">
    <frame src="webacc?taskId=dev.Empty&amp;merge=fw.Body&amp;view=Tasks" name="Mainscreen" title="${requestScope['FrameTitle.Mainscreen']}">
      <frame src="/nps/Empty.html" name="Bitbucket" title="Bitbucket">
</frameset>

</html>

<html>

<head>
  <script src="moz-extension://5847c9bb-864b-490f-93d1-2d752bab5c66/assets/prompt.js"></script>
  <script src="moz-extension://5847c9bb-864b-490f-93d1-2d752bab5c66/assets/prompt.js"></script>
</head>
<frameset cols="340,*,0">
  <frame name="Nav" title="Trama de navegación" src="webacc?taskId=fw.Nav&amp;merge=fw.Nav&amp;view=Tasks" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
    <frame name="Content" title="Trama de contenido" src="webacc?NPService=fw.LaunchService&amp;NPAction=CompleteReturn&amp;returnID=fw.HomePage&amp;firstTime=true" marginheight="15" marginwidth="15" frameborder="0">
      <frame name="Empty" src="webacc?taskId=dev.Empty&amp;merge=fw.Empty&amp;firstTime=true" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" frameborder="0" noresize="">
</frameset>

</html>
<html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Launcher</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/nps/portal/modules/dev/css/sideNavMenu.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/nps/portal/modules/dev/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/nps/portal/modules/dev/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="/nps/portal/modules/dev/common/jQuery/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="moz-extension://5847c9bb-864b-490f-93d1-2d752bab5c66/assets/prompt.js"></script>
  <script src="/nps/portal/modules/dev/common/jQuery/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="moz-extension://5847c9bb-864b-490f-93d1-2d752bab5c66/assets/prompt.js"></script>
</head>

<body scroll="no" style="overflow: hidden; border-right: 1px solid #ccc;">
  <div class="nav-side-menu">
    <div class="menu-list">
      <ul id="menu-content" class="menu-content collapse out">
        <a href="#">
          <li style="background-color: #555555; color: #ffffff;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#1" class="" aria-expanded="true">
            <h3> &nbsp;&nbsp;CAT <span class="arrow"></span>
            </h3>
          </li>
        </a>
        <ul class="sub-menu collapse in" id="1" aria-expanded="true" style="">
          <a href="frameservice?NPService=fw.LaunchService&amp;NPAction=Delegate&amp;delegate=base.SetPassword&amp;launcher=fw.HomePage&amp;lifecycle=Recreate&amp;repeatable=true" target="Content">
            <li>Definir contraseña</li>
          </a>
          <a href="frameservice?NPService=fw.LaunchService&amp;NPAction=Delegate&amp;delegate=base.ModifyGroup&amp;launcher=fw.HomePage&amp;lifecycle=Recreate&amp;repeatable=true" target="Content">
            <li>Modificar grupo</li>
          </a>
          <a href="frameservice?NPService=fw.LaunchService&amp;NPAction=Delegate&amp;delegate=custom.Estado de Usuario&amp;launcher=fw.HomePage&amp;lifecycle=Recreate&amp;repeatable=true" target="Content">
            <li>Estado de Usuario</li>
          </a>
          <a href="frameservice?NPService=fw.LaunchService&amp;NPAction=Delegate&amp;delegate=custom.Verificar Atributos&amp;launcher=fw.HomePage&amp;lifecycle=Recreate&amp;repeatable=true" target="Content">
            <li>Verificar Atributos</li>
          </a>
          <a href="frameservice?NPService=fw.LaunchService&amp;NPAction=Delegate&amp;delegate=custom.Verificar perfil&amp;launcher=fw.HomePage&amp;lifecycle=Recreate&amp;repeatable=true" target="Content">
            <li>Verificar perfil</li>
          </a>
          <a href="frameservice?NPService=fw.LaunchService&amp;NPAction=Delegate&amp;delegate=CheckPWStatus&amp;launcher=fw.HomePage&amp;lifecycle=Recreate&amp;repeatable=true" target="Content">
            <li>Comprobar estado de contraseña</li>
          </a>
        </ul>
        <a href="#">
          <li style="background-color: #555555; color: #ffffff;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#8" class="collapsed">
            <h3> &nbsp;&nbsp;INVITADOS - NAC <span class="arrow"></span> </h3>
          </li>
        </a>
        <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="8">
          <a href="frameservice?NPService=fw.LaunchService&amp;NPAction=Delegate&amp;delegate=custom.Ingresar Invitado&amp;launcher=fw.HomePage&amp;lifecycle=Recreate&amp;repeatable=true" target="Content">
            <li>Ingresar Invitado</li>
          </a>
          <a href="frameservice?NPService=fw.LaunchService&amp;NPAction=Delegate&amp;delegate=custom.Modificar expiracion Invitados&amp;launcher=fw.HomePage&amp;lifecycle=Recreate&amp;repeatable=true" target="Content">
            <li>Modificar expiracion Invitados</li>
          </a>
        </ul>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>

</html>
```

Comment: Al ubicar en el tercer marco, este solo reconoce hasta el cuerpo, no se puede reconocer el resto de etiquetas <body scroll = "no" style = "desbordamiento: oculto; borde derecho: 1px sólido #ccc;"> <div class = "nav-side-menu"> <div class = "menu-list"> <ul id = "menu-content" class = "menu-content colapse out"> <a href="#"> <li style = "color de fondo: # 555555; color: #ffffff;" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = "# 1" class = "" aria-expand = = true "> <h3> & nbsp; & nbsp; CAT <span class =" arrow "> </span> </ h3 >

Comment: driver.switchTo().frame(2);
        List<WebElement> listaElementos = driver.findElements(By.tagName("body"))
             
        
        for (int i = 0; i < listaElementos.size(); i++) {

                      List<WebElement> menu1 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"menu-content\"]/a[1]/li/h3"));
            for (int a = 0; a < menu1.size(); a++) {

                System.out.println("El número total de elemento es " + menu1);
            
            }

            System.out.println("El número total de elementos global  es " + listaElementos.size());

 
        }